batch processing to reduce time
I am trying to build a function to automatically get latitude and longitude. My file is quite large, it has +75k rows and processing time for only 1k is taking around 24 mins. I am trying to include in my code some batch processing but I am not an expert in python, hence online resources are my best option. I have been able to come up with good code for this and there doesn't seem to be much info online on batch processing. Does anyone know how I can make this code faster to process?

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut, GeocoderUnavailable

# Read the CSV file
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("Files/locations.csv")

# Limit to 1000 rows
df_limited = df.limit(1000)

# Define a function to get coordinates
def get_coordinates(address):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="address_geocoder")
    try:
        location = geolocator.geocode(address)
        if location:
            return (location.latitude, location.longitude)
        else:
            return (None, None)
    except (GeocoderTimedOut, GeocoderUnavailable):
        return (None, None)

# Create a UDF (User Defined Function)
coordinates_udf = udf(get_coordinates, StructType([
    StructField("latitude", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("longitude", DoubleType(), True)
]))

# Apply the UDF to create new columns
df_with_coordinates = df_limited.withColumn("coordinates", coordinates_udf(col("ADDRESS")))

# Split the coordinates into separate latitude and longitude columns
df_final = df_with_coordinates.withColumn("latitude", col("coordinates.latitude")) \
                              .withColumn("longitude", col("coordinates.longitude")) \
                              .drop("coordinates")



# Display the final DataFrame
display(df_final)

Would love any input or suggestions! thank you :)

Nominatim is an online service that has a strict rate limit of 1 request per second and they're also explicitly forbidding doing parallel processing. Speeding up your program would violate both of those.

@AKX Agreed that the rate limiting is part of their usage policy (and should be adhered to). However, it seems that they do not enforce it programmatically - i.e., I can make multiple calls in quick succession without any runtime issues.

Thank you everyone this was very helpful!

As mentioned in the comments, you are being limited by the rate-limiting of the service you are using to get the latitude and longitude (not by your program being that slow).
Nominatim explicitely discourages using their service for bulk tasks
What I suggest is you use another source of data. For example you could

get your data directly from the OSM planet as suggested on the Nominatim website
use Openaddresses has data that is also used in the OSM data, but only has addresses, which makes the files a lot smaller
or if you really need to use an API instead of downloading the data at the source, you could use the google maps api, but that is a paid api. (I do not think you are going to be able to find an api that allows you to do geocoding in that amount for free and without rate limiting…)

